# Proof in ruin player problem

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, self-learning

> Let $M_i$ the average number of matches until the player, or lose all,
>   or wins the capital $N$ as it began with the capital $i$. Show that
>   $$M_i=i(N-1);p=\frac{1}{2}$$
>   $$M_i=\frac{i}{1-2p}-\frac{N}{1-2p}\frac{1-(\frac{1-p}{p})^i}{1-(\frac{1-p}{p})^N};p\neq\frac{1}{2}$$

I'm litle lost but I believe we need to assume that
$$P_{WIN}=P_{LOSE}=\frac{1}{2}$$
in each match. Let $X_n$ the Markov Chain to denote the amount of capital in after $n$ matches, then since they start with $i$
$$P(X_{n+1}=i+1|X_n=i)=\frac{1}{2}$$
$$P(X_{n+1}=i-1|X_n=i)=\frac{1}{2}$$

I need to calculate the expectation here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do *not* assume that the probability of losing is equal to the probability of winning; the first line you have given is the formula for a fair game, i.e. when the probability of winning is equal to the probability of winning, i.e. $p=\frac{1}{2}$ as written after the semicolon, whereas the second line is for when $p \neq \frac{1}{2}$.

(The player is betting 1 unit at a time, from what I gather.)

First off, I believe that for a fair game, the solution should in fact be $M_i = i(N-i)$. (Check the boundary condition when the player starts off with capital $N$; then $M_i$ should be zero.)

Moving on, we can denote the time before the player hits $0$ or $N$, starting from $i$, in one random realisation of the game, by $\tau_i$. Then $M_i = \mathbb E [\tau_i]$, and use a first-step decomposition:

$$M_i = 1 + (1-p) M_{i-1} + p M_{i+1}$$

This is a difference equation with boundary conditions $M_0=M_N=0$.

For the fair case when $p = \frac{1}{2}$, $$M_i=A+Bi-i^2$$ is the general solution (you should check this!); by the BCs, $A=0$ and $B=N$, which gives you the first required solution.

For when $p\neq \frac{1}{2}$, the general solution is $$M_i = \frac{i}{1-2p} + A + B \left( \frac {1-p}{p}\right)^i$$

and this should lead you to the second required solution after considering the BCs.

**Alternatively**: as this is a 'show' problem, it is sufficient for you to just check that the given expressions for $M_i$ satisfy the difference equation (i.e. plug it in), which is probably what you are expected to do!

Comment: How you get it $$M_i=A+Bi-i^2$$?

Comment: For the homogeneous part: $A+Bi$ is the general solution to $M_i = \frac{1}{2} M_{i-1} + \frac{1}{2} M_{i+1}$; you get this by noting that your equation can be rewritten as $M_{i+1} - M_i = M_i - M_{i-1}$, i.e. $M$ grows at a constant rate, so $M_i=A+Bi$

Comment: For the particular part: I believe the only (or at least simplest) way is to make an educated guess; in this case, try polynomials, so try plugging $M_i = Ci^2$ into the 'full' difference equation, and you get $C=-1$

Comment: If you are curious about the case when $p \neq \frac{1}{2}$: for the homogenous part, follow DirkGently's answer, and you should be able to see that $\delta_i = \left( \frac{1-p}{p} \right)^i$ or $\delta_i = 0$; then you should be able to find an expression for $M_i$ after a bit more work. Again, for the particular case, try polynomials, beginning with a linear term (as your solution to the homogeneous part does not contain a linear term this time!).

Answer (score 2):

By the law of total probability, we have $$M_i=1+p M_{i+1} + (1-p) M_{i-1},$$ with $M_0=M_n=0$. 
It can now be shown that the given solution is the answer to the above recursion. I believe the recursion can be solved along the following lines. But it seemed tedious.

To solve the homogenous case $M_i=p M_{i+1} + (1-p) M_{i-1}$, we write $$p(M_{i+1}-M_i)=(1-p)(M_i-M_{i-1}).$$Let $\delta_i = M_i - M_{i-1}$ to get
$$\delta_{i+1}=\frac{1-p}p\delta_i$$ and $\delta_1 = M_1$. We also have $\sum\delta_i=M_N-M_0=0$. So we can solve for $M_1$ and find the other $M_i$ as well.

*Update:* I made corrections based on the comment below, but did not complete the solution of the recursive equation.

Comment: It should be noted that the given decomposition for $M_i$ in this solution is missing a $1$, and the boundary condition on $M_N$ should be $0$ and not $1$. Nevertheless, everything below this is a correct method of solving the given difference equation, and is in fact the homogeneous case of the correct difference equation (which is the part needed to be solved before considering the inhomogeneous case). Having said so, this process is indeed difficult; sometimes the solution is given (i.e. you need not derive it.)

Comment: @KenWei Thanks. I confused the expected time to ruin or win with the probability of winning.